# Hiding a link if a specific client is logged in with PHP

Tags: php, html

New to coding and having some issues finding an answer to what I believe is a simple question. I am trying to hide link if we have a specific client logged in.

For example: our website allows for our clients (restaurants) to add their new employees into our system which provides the employee with all the policies and handbooks they need read over and sign electronically.

When the client enter in a new employee, they are sent to a confirmation page (`onboarding_addemployee_complete.php`) which has a link to the policies and handbooks they to review.

I want to hide this link from one specific client (client id is 280 in the database). There is a restriction already set for clients that need access to add their employees. I believe I would have to add another restriction stating that if clientid = 280 then $onboardingLink should not be displayed.

Am I going in the correct direction?

```
<?php

include( "header.php" );

//Restrict Users who do not have the Onboarding service
if (!hasService($USERID,'Onboarding')) {header( 'Location: home.php' ,true,301) ;}

checkAccessToFunctionality($USERID,$USERTYPE,'ADDEMPLOYEE',true);


if(!isset( $_GET['id']))
{
    echo '<br/><div style="padding-left:40px;">You have reached this page in error. Please click \'Home\'.</div>';
    exit(0);

}


$employeeID = $_GET['id'];
$locationID = getData($employeeID,'tblonboardingemployees','locationid');
if(userCanAccessLocation($USERID,$locationID)==false)
{


    echo '<br/><div style="padding-left:40px;">You do not have access to this page.</div>';
    exit(0);

}
$onboardingLink = getData($employeeID,'tblonboardingemployees','onboardinglink');

    //Show the completion message.
?>


<div style="width:<?php echo $interface_interiorarea; ?>"><hr></div>
<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>
<center>
<table><tr><td style="vertical-align:top;padding-top:10px;padding-right:15px;"><img src="images/checkmark.png"></td>
<td>
<div style="text-align:left;width:600px;font-size:18px;"><B>The employee has been added</B><br>
<span class="sectioninstructions" style="font-size:15px;">The employee will be sent an email with information regarding the onboarding process. The email will contain a link that the employee can click to begin the process. The same link can be used to resume the process if the employee is interrupted for any reason.
<br>&nbsp;<br>
<span class="sectioninstructions" style="font-size:15px;">If you would like to begin the onboarding process now, you may click the following link to begin: </span><br>&nbsp;<br><b> <?php echo '<a href="login_employee.php?id='.$onboardingLink.'">Begin the Onboarding Process</a></b>'; ?>
<br>&nbsp;<br><a href="home.php">Go back to the home page</a></span>
</div>
</td></tr></table>
</center>


<?php

include( "footer.php" );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a bit flexible you could do something like this

```
$but_not_these_emps = array(280);

if(userCanAccessLocation($USERID,$locationID)==false || 
   in_array($USERID, $but_not_these_emps) )
{
```

Not totally sure I have used the right variable `$USERID` or put it in the right `if` statement, but I am sure you get the basic idea

Comment: Agreed, storing the values in an array is a much better approach for the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is correct. An if conditional can be used to display the link (or not display the link) according to the clientID as follows:

```
<?php 
    // only if the $clientID is different to 280 will the link 
    // be printed on the screen
  if ($clientID != 280)
  {
    echo '<a href="login_employee.php?id='.$onboardingLink.'"
    >Begin the Onboarding Process</a>'; 
  } 
?>
```

Let me know if that helped